# Does wacom intuos have plug-and-play functionality?

Tags: drawing-tablet

I have recently started teaching (a non-graphic-design-related course) at uni, and was looking at buying a simple tablet to plug into the computer that controls the projector to use as a basic whiteboard as the actual whiteboard is on the other side of the room.

I was looking at the wacom intuos pen small, as i dont need very complicated functionality. My only question is whether it is plug-and-play with windows 7, or do i need to install drivers? I do not have administrator access to the computers at uni, so i am worried that i won't be able to use it.

I know that drivers exist, but i am hoping that they are used for the extended functionality of the tablet such as pressure sensitivity and the like, and that simple mouse-like operations might be possible with plug-and-play.

Is it possible to use the wacom intuos without the drivers at all? and if not, are there any similarly cheap graphics tablets that would work without installing drivers?

Comment: Welcome guskenny83! Thanks for posting your question. Unfortunately, GD.SE is not designed to handle issues regarding technical support. If you are seeking technical assistance with an application, please try the application manufacture's web site or their website. We are confident you will find answers. If you want to know more about GD.SE, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 7 comes with tablet drivers, yes. It works out of the box, if you dont want to be fancy and work over standard USB*. It does not work for any of the primary uses i use a tablet for, so I never use it, but as a pointer its fine (on a single monitor setup).

* so theres no guarantee a wireless tablet will work without drivers

PS: There is a catch 13, The tablet functionality of win 7 can be uninstalled. So a especially paranoid IT department might make this untrue. Test.

PPS: This question belongs to super user